# Terminfo definitions don't work?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, tty

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a run-of-the-mill Dell desktop computer.

I have a Wyse WY-60 serial terminal hooked up to the serial port (ttyS0).

When the terminal is in VT100 emulation mode, and agetty is set to use VT100 emulation, all features work as they should. This is my `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf` file:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/agetty -hL 19200 ttyS0 vt100
```

But when I try to put the terminal in any other emulation (i.e. Wyse 50, Adds A2, etc.), and change the corresponding part of that agetty line, the terminal doesn't work correctly (displays a bunch of escape-sequence garbage on commands like `ls`).

In other words, I change the Wyse terminal's emulation in its internal setup utility, then change `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf` to the following:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/agetty -hL 19200 ttyS0 wyse50
```

-or-

```
respawn
exec /sbin/agetty -hL 19200 ttyS0 wy50
```

I *do* have terminfo defitions stored for this and a million other models of terminal, in all 3 or 4 places where the terminfo library is stored on Ubuntu. So what's up with this not working? I want to be able to add some more dumb terminals to my system, such as the Wyse WY-30 and WY-50, which are not capable of VT100 emulation.

Can't get it to work with Wyse-50, ADDS Viewpoint 60, Adds A2, IBM-PC, or any other terminal emulation besides VT100.

Comment: Is the `TERM` environment variable set correctly after you log in on that tty? `echo "$TERM"`

Comment: Yes, typing that on the terminal causes it to print the same thing I have in the /etc/init/ttyS0.conf file

Comment: Did you ever have any luck resolving this?

Comment: No. This is a problem with Ubuntu.